# Are functions like this one still continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R} $. I wonder if this function is still continuous at $0$ if $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) =f(0)$. I believe it is, but I am not sure since the left-hand side limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as a function from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb R$ the function is continuous. The limit as $x \to a$ in the definition of continuity is to be taken in the space where the function is defined.  There happens to be another space in which the domain can be embedded but where the function is not defined, but this fact is irrelevant.